# Conditional show/hide for react radio button in .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a radio button that when true/checked it shows that option as select. The problem I have is that all options are selected as true within my radio group mapping. Here is an codesandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/73k0onx32x

```
  <RadioGroup
    aria-label="matches"
    name="matches"
    value={String(this.state.value)}
    onChange={this.handlePersonToggle}
  >
    {data.map(person => (
      <FormControlLabel
        onClick={e => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        key={String(person.Id)}
        value={String(person.Id)}
        control={<Radio color="primary" />}
        label={
          <div>
            {this.state.checked === true && <div>if true show</div>}
          </div>
        }
      />
    ))}
  </RadioGroup>
```

Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Your `checked` property is shared with all radio options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/l261qp002m

[image]

---

Final code

```
class RadioButtonsGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 1
  };

  handlePersonToggle = event => {
    // console.log(typeof event.target.value)   //string
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <RadioGroup
        aria-label="matches"
        name="matches"
        value={String(this.state.value)}
      >
        {data.map(person => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              onClick={e => this.handlePersonToggle(e)}
              key={String(person.Id)}
              value={String(person.Id)}
              control={<Radio color="primary" />}
              label={
                <div>
                  {this.state.value == person.Id ? <div>if true show</div> : ""}
                </div>
              }
            />
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

---

There are several things that we need to fix.

Firstly, we don't need the `checked` attribute on the `FormControlLabel` component and also don't need to manage the state checked, just the `value` attribute of `RadioGroup` and `FormControlLabel` components are enough, as long as they match, it will know which option is selected.

Secondly, since we're passing the  `String(this.state.value)`, hence, our `event.target.value` become a `string` rather than an `integer`. Therefore, we can't use the strict comparison `===`, we use the `==` instead.

Finally, we write the event handler for the `onClick` event on the `FormControlLabel` component.

Answer (score 1):

Your component state contains a single value, checked, which can be set to true or false. You will need something like a value containing the id of the selected item.

Try something like this

```
<RadioGroup
  aria-label="matches"
  name="matches"
  value={String(this.state.value)}
  onChange={this.handlePersonToggle}
>
  {data.map(person => (
    <FormControlLabel
      onClick={e => this.setState({ selectedItem: person.Id })}
      checked={this.state.selectedItem === person.Id}
      key={String(person.Id)}
      value={String(person.Id)}
      control={<Radio color="primary" />}
      label={
        <div>
          {this.state.selectedItem === person.Id && <div>if true show</div>}
        </div>
      }
    />
  ))}
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'r onClick handling is wrong. I have fixed the problem as below also

```
  <RadioGroup
    aria-label="matches"
    name="matches"
    value={String(this.state.value)}
    onChange={this.handlePersonToggle}
  >
    {data.map(person => (
      <FormControlLabel
        onClick={e => this.setState({ checked: person.Id })}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        key={String(person.Id)}
        value={String(person.Id)}
        control={<Radio color="primary" />}
        label={
          <div>{this.state.checked === person.Id && <div>true</div>}</div>
        }
      />
    ))}
  </RadioGroup>
```